# How to download podcasts in Rhythmbox without folders

Tags: directory, rhythmbox

I use Rhythmbox to download my podcasts to my laptop, using RSS feeds. All the files for any particular feed are gathered into a single folder. That is nice and structured but when I transfer the folders to my phone for listening the music player on my phone does not display the podcast file titles. For every file I need to make several button presses to display the file titles. this gets to be very tedious.

I have discovered that if I remove the files from the folders on my laptop I do not have this problem.

My question is:

Is there a setting for Rhythmbox that will allow me to download the podcasts as separate file entities, rather than aggregated into folders? I don't see such a setting and am having to think of ways of automating the extraction of the files from the folders on my laptop. I have found a script that does this but it's dangerous in that if I mad a mistake in the terminal and ran the script in the wrong directory I could really mess up a lot of folder structures.